# Redeployment of Azure Function does not happen

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I am experimenting with an Azure Function in PowerShell to answer a simple HTTP request.

I am editing directly in the Azure Portal.

I do not understand how deployment works. I assume it should directly redeploy after "save".

When I change my code and test it within Azure Portal I get debug results in the console/log and expected results in the HTTP-Output.

However: When I call the function from a browser, it returns different results. I think these are old results, so either the function is not redeployed or some cache / proxy is fooling my browser.

How can I see if redeployment took place after "save" in the AzurePortal?
How can I check debug / console output of a real invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the function was "disabled" - after enabling it again all works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

First, I run with the default Code from the Http Trigger Function (PowerShell Runtime) - i.e., created in the Azure Portal and edited the Function Code from the Portal itself > Saved > Clicked on Run again.

If we save the function, it will just save the changes in the code. We have to run again the Function for changes made in the Code Logic for new response.

[image]

You can see how many times your function in the Azure Function App is executed, in Monitor > Invocations with more information such as Response Code for every invocation (Function Run), Execution Time, [image]

And I have updated the Function Code two times after 1st run of the default Code. Here in the Activity Logs, you can see number of times updated the **run.ps1** function code updates registered:

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

I have run the Azure Function App PowerShell Http Trigger in the browser tab with its function URL for 4 times and the invocations are display after 4 minutes of time because my function app is hosted in Consumption plan:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support! I dont see any invocations even though I changed code and executed the request again from my browser. I see the "Write run.ps1" in the Activity log. should I see an entry for "recompiling" or "deploying" also? I cant read your screenshot ...

Comment: Please refresh your browser for screenshot reading and For each run, you'll see invocations in the monitor tab and it will take 3 to 5 minutes time for getting logs if function app is hosted in Consumption Plan as you can see in my above Gif Image shown and updated the answer by running the function URL not only in the `Code+Test `menu and also in the **browser tab**.